# Bookmark all open webpages in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

My Firefox is 11.0. I wonder how to bookmark currently open webpages in the tabs at once?

I remember with previous versions of Firefox, there was an option in the "Bookmarks" menu for such purpose, but I cannot find it any longer.

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10. I haven't got a time to install a newer version of Ubuntu yet, but I hope that I can bookmark all open webpages in my Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click a tab, `Bookmark All Tabs...`. [Hotkey](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> / <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Apple keyboards).